# Use JSON to represent a set of strings

Tags: javascript, json, set

I'm reading JavaScript Pocket Reference 3rd edition. The autor stated in chapter 5 - Objects - page 75:

> JavaScript objects are dynamic - properties can usually be added and deleted - but they can be used to simulate the static objects and "structs" of statically typed languages. They can also be used (by ignoring the value part of the string-to-value mapping) to represent sets of strings.

I'm trying to verify the truth value of the last statement. Well I created an valid object as follows:

```
var origin = { "x" : 0, "y" : 0};
```

When I ignored the values of the string-to-value mapping:

```
var origin = { "x", "y"};
```

Running this code gives the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ','
```

Do I miss something?

Comment: Wut? Newer Javascript versions allow the `{ x, y }` syntax, which is simply shorthand for `{ x: x, y: y }`. But it doesn't act like a set at all. The author probably means something like `{ [x]: null, [y]: null }`, i.e. not really using the value part. But you still need to provide it syntactically.

Answer (score 0):

You must omit the double quote for [shorthand property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015)

```js
const x = y = 0
var origin = {
  x,
  y
};

console.log(origin)
```

Comment: This doesn't act like a set though…

Answer (score 0):

For [this new syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015) to work, you need to send in the variables inside, not values:

```js
var x = 0;
var y = 0;
var origin = {x, y};

console.log(origin);
```

**Clarification:** The above doesn't act like a set. But to clarify your question on *"Running this code gives the following error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ','`"* and * Do I miss something?* I have answered the above.

Comment: This doesn't act like a set though…

Comment: @deceze Yes, you're right. But, isn't the original problem with _When I ignored the values of the string-to-value mapping_?

Comment: It's pretty vague what the author is trying to say there. But getting the syntax to not throw errors and implementing what the author meant are still two different things…

Comment: @deceze I just clarified it in the answer, can you check if it's right, if not, I am happy to remove it. I know I can trust you! 